# Reloading state without refreshing ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui router, now I want to filter data using params in url (search part of url), without reloading state - I dont need to ask server everytime I want to find something in collection.

my idea is to listen event $routeChangeSuccess, take all search params and apply angular filter on collection with them.

I tried to do something like this

```
<a ui-sref="invoices.issued({ invoice_type_id: invoiceType.id })" ui-sref-opts="{reload: false}">{{invoiceType.name}}</a>
```

to change url for example to *?invoice_type_id=2* but without any success (state is reloading)...

then I wrote my own directive which listens *$locationChangeStart* and uses *reloadOnSearch: false* in state provider, but i feel like a rewriting ui-router functionality (reactions on loading page with some params set, highlighting active link etc...)

So I want to ask is it possible with ui-router? If is what am I doing wrong? Or is there a completely different approach how to do filtering?

Thanks Blazek

Comment: I'd suggest setting the routeParams to a variable and inject/use that in your filter rather than rewriting a bunch of modules.

Comment: Thanks, yes I would like to do it, but I'm not really sure how, because ui-sref options does not work in the way I described in my question. I would like to avoid downloading whole collection again, there are hundreds of records so I want to reduce server usage and filter data on client side

Comment: It sounds like what you want is to create a filter/factory and inject your search params into it and pass it back to the controller. I've never done it, but this resource may help https://egghead.io/search?q=filters

Comment: yes, something like this, but especially a must not reload state on this action...

Answer (score 0):

Another option to prevent redirect to your state:

```
$transitions.onBefore({}, function($transition$) {
 if ($transition$.$to().name === '[state name]') {
   return false;
 }
});
```